запуск новых контейнеров из контейнера
у меня есть докерфайл апи,
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-1.70.0 as chef
WORKDIR app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef AS builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock

FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/blue_tractor_api /

ENV DOCKER_HOST unix:///var/run/docker.sock

ENTRYPOINT ["./blue_tractor_api"]
#CMD ["./blue_tractor_api"]
CMD ["docker", "run", "--privileged", "-it", "blue_tractor_api", "--network=host"]


но не смотря на то, что я говорю, что контейнер будет использовать Docker socket из хоста, монтируя его в /var/run/docker.sock, доступ из контейнера я к нему не получаю и не могу запускать контейнеры изнутри текущего контейнера. как мне это сделать?
